# Объясните как спарсить второй div из html-страницы

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, парсер

Моя проблема состоит в том, что мне нужно спарсить div в котором находиться таймер.
[image: Html-страница]

Но по прописанному мною коду, парсится div, который находиться выше. Возможно мне нужно, как-то пропустить данную строку, но мне не известно это, читал только про decompose (bs4) и то понять куда его прописать так до меня, и не дошло. Помогите, пожалуйста, осуществить парс "таймера" (Строчка 'Update').

```py
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    div = soup.find("div", class_="top-new") # Все объекты

    projects = []

    for divw in div.find_all("div", class_="top-w"): # Каждый объект
        wert = divw.find_all("div", style_=()) 

        projects.append({
            'Name': wert[0].a.text.strip(), # Название
            'Update': wert[0].div.text # Обновление
            })

    for project in projects:
        print(project)

def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()

def main():
    parse (get_html("http://anistar.ru/raspisanie-vyhoda-seriy-ongoingov.html")) # Страница

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если проблема только с парсингом таймеров, ее можно решить таким кодом

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('http://anistar.ru/raspisanie-vyhoda-seriy-ongoingov.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content)
timers = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'timer_cal'})

for timer in timers:
    print(timer.text.strip())
```

[Хороший видео гайд по BS4](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xQTJi2tqgk)

Answer (score 0):

Для `BeautifulSoup` можно через css-селектор найти:

```py
timer_cal = divw.select_one('.timer_cal').get_text(strip=True)
```

---

А можно искать по этому xpath: `//div[@class="timer_cal"]/span`

Он описывает поиск как: ищем `span`, у которых в родителях `div` с классом `timer_cal`.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Предлагаете кодом описать? Да и тут все понятно же: ищем span'ы у которых в родителях div с классом "timer_cal"